# Displaying date based on current day in php

Tags: php, date

I am using the following code, to display a date based on the current day i.e if today is Monday or Tuesday, it should display the next Wednesday date and if any other date, it should display next mondays date.

Below is the code:

```
<?php
    $date = str_replace("/", "-", $date);
    $nextWed = date("l jS F, Y",strtotime('next wednesday'));
    $nextMon = date("l jS F, Y",strtotime('next monday'));

if(date('D', $timestamp) === 'Mon' or date('D', $timestamp) === 'Tue' ){ 

echo '<div class="time-note">Order your box before Tuesday 11.59pm and get it delivered on '.$nextWed .'</div>';}
else {
    echo '<div class="time-note">Order your box before Sunday 11.59pm and get it delivered on '.$nextMon.'</div>';}?>
```

If I view the out put today it still echoes `Order your box before Sunday 11.59pm and get it delivered on Monday 19th October 2015`. Whereas it should say `Order your box before Tuesday 11.59pm and get it delivered on Monday 14th October 2015`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you're missing is the `$timestamp`

Add this line `$timestamp = time();` directly underneath `$nextMon = date("l jS F, Y",strtotime('next monday'));`

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
if(date('D') === 'Mon' or date('D') === 'Tue' )
```